# What is the workflow for creating a coded UI test with assertions in VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, testing, coded-ui-tests

I am creating a coded UI test with assertions in VS2010.  Here is what I want to do:

1. Run the application.
2. Test whether the text on a button is "button1".
3. Click the button.
4. Test whether the text on the button is "clicked!"

There seems to be no simple way to do this with the coded UI test.  In particular, whenever I start recording and then run the application, the 'add assertions' button is greyed out.

It seems as if the only way to do this is in pieces: first launch the application, then close the coded UI test gadget, then go into the test and right click on Generate Code for Coded UI Test, then use the "Add assertions" button in the gadget to add the gadget, then edit the code because it places the assertions before it launches the application, etc.

Is there a way to do this in one fell swoop?

Answer (score 0):

Automate "launching application from GUI" with Play and record functionality.